# Type Family as Argument to Type Synonym

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families

I have a data type that looks like

```
data G f n a where 
  G :: a -> G f n a -> G f (f n) a
```

It's a container indexed by naturals, which takes a function that determines how to proceed inductively.

I can define a type synonym easily like

```
type G' n a = G S n a
```

But I'd like to be able to use the identity function.

I tried using Data.Functor.Identity, but even when redefined with PolyKinds, I can't get a type-level function on Naturals (`:k Identity => Nat -> Nat`), so I turned to type families, defining

```
type family Id a where 
  Id a = a
```

which, cool, it compiles. Unfortunately, I supply `type G'' n a = G Id n a` and I get the error message of

```
The type family ‘Id’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
In the type synonym declaration for ‘G''’
```

So is there a way I can use a type family in a type synonym? That seems like the ideal end state.

(The extensions I'm currently using are 
`{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeInType, PolyKinds #-}`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't pass type families (or type synonyms) around unsaturated, but you can pass around a token which represents that type family. Then when it's time to apply the type family to an argument, you can look up the token you were given.

```
type family Apply (token :: *) (n :: Nat) :: Nat

data G token n a where
    G :: a -> G token n a -> G token (Apply token n) a
```

Now you can define tokens and how to apply them.

```
data SToken
type instance Apply SToken n = S n

data IdToken
type instance Apply IdToken n = n
```

And your synonyms:

```
type G' = G SToken
type GId = G IdToken
```

This trick - passing around representations of functions, rather than functions themselves - is called *defunctionalisation* and was [originally developed in the 70s](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.5892&rep=rep1&type=pdf) as an implementation technique for higher-order functional programming languages. (That paper's a terrific read, by the way.)

I don't know if this is the only way to do what you want, but it's more or less how `singletons` does it. More info [on the `singletons` author's blog](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/defunctionalization-for-the-win/).